# javascriptでevernoteアプリを開発していて、サンドボックス環境からプロダクション環境（本番環境）への移行ができない。トークンが取得できない。

Tags: javascript, monaca, html5, oauth

お世話になります。

javascriptを用いて、evernoteアプリを開発しています。

サンドボックス環境ではきちんとトークンが取得できるのですが、プロダクション環境（本番環境）ではevernoteのトークンが取得できず、困っております。

具体的には、Evernoteのサイト（https://dev.evernote.com/intl/jp/doc/start/javascript.php）からリンクを貼られていたサンプルコード（https://github.com/evernote/phonegap-example/blob/master/HelloWorld/www/js/index.js）をほぼそのまま流用しています。

サンドボックス環境では、トークンが取得できるのですが、プロダクション環境ではそれができません。

具体的には、ユーザー名とパスワードを入力する画面が現れ、承認ボタンを押すことができるのですが、その後、添付の画面に移り、結局トークンが取得することができません。
[image: エラー画面]

サンドボックス環境からプロダクション環境に移るに当たり変更したことは、evernotehostnameを、「https://sandbox.evernote.com」から「http://www.evernote.com」に変更しただけです。

サンドボックス環境では動くにもかかわらず、本番環境では動かず、困っております。２つは全く同じ環境だと思っていたのですが、何かが違うのでしょうか。

もし、改善案がお分かりの方がいらっしゃったら、情報提供いただけないでしょうか。

よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Comment: 利用したことがないのでよくわかりませんが、[サンドボックス環境で使っている API キーをプロダクション環境に移行するには、何が必要ですか？](https://dev.evernote.com/intl/jp/support/faq.php#activatekey)の、キーのアクティベーションは有効化していますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。

はい、キーのアクティベーションは有効化しています。evernoteのサイト（https://dev.evernote.com/intl/jp/support/faq.php#activatekey）の手続きに従いevernote社に連絡し、有効化したとの返事がかえってきました。

evernote社に連絡してプロダクション環境でのキーのアクティベーションを行い、後はホスト名をhttp://www.evernote.comに変えれば動作するはずなのですが、うまく動作しません。